# Density of convex set at a point

Tags: reference-request, convex-geometry

I'm interested in the following notion of density for a (convex) set $X$ at a point $x$, defined as

$$D(x) = \lim_{r \to 0^+}\frac{\mu(X \cap B(x,r))}{\mu(B(x,r))}.$$

Here, $B(x, r)$ is a ball centered at $x$ with radius $r$, and $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure. In particular for a polygon, this can be used to define the interior angle at a vertex.

I'm quite sure I've seen this before, but I can't recall where. Googling I was only able to find [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3491213/is-there-a-lower-bound-to-density-at-boundary-points-of-a-convex-set) question which at least confirms it's a known thing. Does anyone know of any resource that talks about this value and perhaps proves some basic properties?

Comment: Did you try simply searching for ["Lebesgue density" + "convex set"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Lebesgue+density%22+%22convex+set%22)? Or are you looking for something a lot more specific that would be buried in this search? If it's just *Lebesgue density* you're interested in (and you didn't know this term for it), then search for "Lebesgue density". (FYI, I've posted a lot of things about or using this notion -- see [this google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Lebesgue+density%22+%22Renfro%22&filter=0)).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Ah thank you, Lebesgue density was just what I was looking for.